# Is there any debugger that supports step-back?

Tags: ida, ollydbg, debugging, debuggers, x64dbg

In Ida when I use debugger, but I can't step back.

Is there any debugger that allow go backwards?

Comment: What you're looking for is typically called replay debugging and is supported by GDB 7 and newer and since 2017 by the [store version of WinDbg](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windbg/2017/09/25/time-travel-debugging-in-windbg-preview/) (they call it something else, though). But your question as it stands is eliciting recommendations/opinions, so not a good fit for Q&A. I recommend you ask on [softwarerecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and we close _this_ one.

Answer (score 1):

In general, stepping back for a debugger is a hard problem. `gdb` has a limited *step back* feature but it comes with a cost, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/reversible.html).

But, when you think about it, the whole difficulty solved by the programmer when debugging is to step-back until it reach the bug. This is the whole difficulty and we do not have a nice and automated solution for it right now.